# apache + ubuntu 14.04 + 403 forbidden

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I have a PHP app up and running on my one server having ubuntu 12.04. I have to move to another server now and I want to move on ubuntu 14.04. I installed apache there and did all require configurations.

But I am always getting :

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 23.250.20.169 Port 80

Not sure why ?
I am on it form last 3 days and I have tried every damn link of google . i have tried one of yours as well and its not working.

Can someone please help me out.